# How to implement expandable panels in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, expandable

Is there an easy way to create expandable/collapsible ?

Screenshot when you click on "Show More Detail" button, the description section expands with animation:
[image]

Comment: Please try with ExpnasionTile widget. For more info refer https://dev.to/rrtutors/flutter-expansiontile-example-4i84

Comment: You can also try this https://medium.flutterdevs.com/expansion-tile-in-flutter-d2b7ba4a1f4b

Answer (score 2):

You should use ExpansionPanel widget for this.

[Basic Expansion Panel Widget Example](https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/how-to-create-expansion-panel-list-in-flutter-2fba574366e8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `expandable: ^5.0.1`.

I prefer using this instead of `ExpansionPanel` because it is a lot more customizable and easy to use.

[Flutter Expandable (pub.dev)](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable)